# Persist sort/filter selections

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app, sorting

One feature of the SE sites is that many (most?) of the pages will persist their sort and filtering options.

For example, when I click on the **Questions** link on any of my regular sites in a browser, it always defaults to the **Newest** sort, because that is how I prefer to read the sites and is the way I more than likely was reading it during my last session.

The iOS app doesn't always do this.

If you goto a site, tap **Questions**, choose a sort, tap a question, and then tap the back link, the sort persists.

If you goto a site, tap **Questions**, choose a sort, goto another site, ..., then go back to a site and tap **Questions**, the sort will be back at **Active**.

This is inconsistent and annoying.  Please persist the sorts/filters during a session and between sessions.

Comment: I was going to post a request that tag view/search default to "newest", but this'll get the job done even better! This will match the behavior of the web site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been implemented in the app and will be available in Beta version **1.0.1.86**. It should also be available in the Appstore in the next update.

Comment: Any way to "forget/reset" the selections? Just asking, I know we don't have such way in the desktop site.

Comment: @ShadowWizard sorry, not currently. If you really wanted to do it, deleting the app will force that to happen, since they are cached locally.

Comment: I just tested this by selecting a tag, changing sort from `Relevant` to `Active`, pressing `Cancel`, and selecting the tag again. It was `Relevant` again. Am I missing something?

Comment: @mhlester we had decided not to persist on search. Yet, this is a usecase I hadn't considered where it does make sense. Let me see what I can do.

Comment: yay, thank you! though i can't think of an instance where you wouldn't want search to persist. the same search would probably be for the same reason

Comment: @ArieLitovsky I agree with mhlester here - it's very annoying to have to switch the sort from Relevant to Active or Newest every time you want to look at the questions with a given tag.