# Persist sort criteria of tagged questions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, ios-app, sorting

The questions list itself [already remembers the sort and filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229101/persist-sort-filter-selections) in the iOS app.

However, I would like the same for tagged questions. For example, sometimes when I choose a tag, the app automatically sorts the list by 'Relevant', but I would like to do so by 'Newest' by default so I don't have to do this every time I search a new tag.

Comment: Thanks, this is the right place indeed. This was already suggested and done for question sorting, but not for tags.

Comment: Great! I did a quick search and I couldn't find someone suggested it already.

Comment: All good, it's a different request and sometimes it's hard to find dupes. :)

Answer (score 1):

It took a while, but it's here. The new tag results screen (currently only available on the Beta version) will now persist the sorting criteria. Like with all sort criteria in our app, these are persisted per-site.

[image]

This change will be available beginning with beta version **1.1.0.124**.